# Can I reuse variables used in function in javascript function?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

```
string empCode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EMP_CODE"].ToString();
        string empName = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["EMP_NAME"].ToString();
        string gradeCode = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["GRADE_CODE"].ToString();

        tr = new TableRow();

        td = new TableCell();
        td.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript: " +
            "if(confirm(empName)==true){self.close();}" +  //this Line
            "else{return;}");
```

I want to reuse empName in the commented part.
Is there a way to reuse it?

Comment: You can inline the value into the generated javascript like this `$"if(confirm('{empName}')==true){self.close();}"`

Comment: If you do, you can't use variables.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Put the variable value in there or use it as a variable in that string of code?

Comment: I want to use a variable declared in c# in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as show below,

```
td.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript: " +
        "if(confirm(" + empName + ") === true){self.close();}" +  //this Line
        "else{return;}");
```

or try

```
td.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript: " +
        "var empName=" + empName + "; if(confirm(empName) === true){self.close();}" +  //this Line
        "else{return;}");
```